# Inequality for Conditional Variance

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-functions

Let $X,Y$ be real random variables with joint density $p(x,y)$. Let the variance of $X, Y$ be $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Var} (Y)=\sigma^2$. The conditional variance of $X$ for a given $Y=y$ is defined as 
$$f(y) :=\operatorname{Var}(X|Y=y) = \mathbb{E}\left[X^2|Y=y]-\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y\right]^2$$

**Question**

What classes of densities, $p(x,y)$, satisfy the following inequality?
   $$f(y) \le \sigma^2,\qquad\forall y$$

**Observation**

1. By the total variance law, we have $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)] \leq \sigma^2$.
2. If $X,Y$ are jointly gaussian, the above inequality is satisfied.
3. (Trivial) If $X,Y$ are independent, the above inequality is satisfied

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent, then $f=\sigma^2$.

Comment: The class of densities is  very large (too large?). I would not expect very much in this general setting. Perhaps check the literature on copulas...

Comment: In fact, you may take any distribution you want for $Y$, and then any collection of random variables indexed by $y$, $(X_y)_y$, whose variances are uniformly bounded by $\sigma^2$. Then first sample $Y$, and conditionally on $\{Y=y\}$, sample independently $X$ distributed as $X_y$...

Comment: @Oliver: I wanted to characterize the densities $p(x,y)$ which satisfy the above property. Your constructive answer is a correct answer, however, it is hard to characterize it.